# Understanding the conditions of this for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

I would like to understand the conditions of this for loop

```
for (std::vector<sofa::core::collision::DetectionOutput*>::const_iterator it = contacts.begin(); it != contacts.end(); it++, i++)
```

I would elaborate on what exactly I'd like to understand but I don't know if my question would even make sense. Just an explanation on what that for loop is doing would suffice

Thanks,

Comment: Have you ever seen or used a loop to iterate over a vector using iterators (usually shown and taught in most decent beginners books)? This is really the same here. The only difference is that this loop also increments `i` at the end of each iteration.

Comment: It's taking a vector of [SOFA collision contact points](https://www.sofa-framework.org/api/master/sofa/html/classsofa_1_1core_1_1collision_1_1_detection_output.html), and then going from the start of the vector to the end, one at a time. `it` is a pointer to the current element in the vector, `it++` moves that pointer to the next element in the vector, and `i++` increments some variable `i` that isn't shown in your snippet. The loop will run until it's been through every element in the vector, as `contacts.end()` is a pointer to one element past the end of the vector.

Comment: Replace the type name with `auto` and then it's a regular for loop.

Comment: By the way, any `for` loop can be translated into a `while` loop. A `for` loop like `for (Init; Condition; Increment) { Statement; }` can be translated into `{ Init; while (Condition) { Statement; Increment; } }`. Now please try to do the same with your own loop (but with proper formatting) and see if it's easier to see what it does.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a constant vector iterator of type `std::vector<sofa::core::collision::DetectionOutput*` that will iterate through each `contacts` room till `contacts.end()`, the variable `i` is incremented in each iteration along `it++`.

`const_iterator` indicates the compiler that if any portion of code inside the loop body attempts to alter the value of any room of the vector container, should generate an error.

The equivalent line can be deduced in the following way using type deduction:

```
for (const auto it = contacts.begin(); it != contacts.end(); it++, i++)
```

Another alternative approach is as follows:

```
for (const auto& it : contacts) {
  i++;
  .
  .
}
```

In this approach, each room iterating through `contacts` is assumed to be `it`. Use this only if you don't need to manipulate values with array indices.

Comment: Thank you Rohan!

Comment: I would opt for using the even simpler [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), eg: `for (const auto &contact : contacts) { ... i++; }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Nice idea, amended answer.

Comment: @RohanBari I would not suggesting naming the loop variable `it` in a range `for` loop, since it is not an iterator, the actual iterator used is hidden from the coder.

Comment: minor note, in the for auto loop, the `i++;` should be at the end of the loop.